# Recursive Maze in Java

Tags: java, recursion, dictionary, maze

I have written a short Java code for solving a simple maze problem to go from S to G.

I do not understand where the problem is going wrong.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class tester
  {
static char [][] grid={
        {'.','.'},
        {'.','.'},
        {'S','G'},
};

static int a=2;
static int b=2;


static boolean findpath(int x, int y)
{
     if((x > grid.length-1) || (y > grid[0].length-1) || (x < 0 || y < 0))
        {
            return false;
        }
     else if(x==a && y==b){
        return true;
    }

     else if (findpath(x,y-1) == true){
        return true;
    }
     else if (findpath(x+1,y) == true){
        return true;
    }
     else if (findpath(x,y+1) == true) {
    return true;
}
     else if (findpath(x-1,y) == true){ 
    return true;
}
return false;

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean result=findpath(2,0);
    System.out.print(result);
    }
```

}

I am giving the starting position directly and goal is defined in a & b. Do help.

Comment: Describe the algorithm you are trying to implement with your code.  (Like most programming processes, start with a algorithm and then implement.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no cell like (2;2). Array is numbered from 0. You also get infinitive recursion, because you visit one cell multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever this cryptic algorithm is trying to achieve, the function with `y` argument set to 2 will immediately return false as `grid[0].length-1==1` and the condition `y > grid[0].length-1` is true. So `if(x==a && y==b){` will never be true.